# Convert String to Array of Integers in Swift 3?

Tags: swift

I'm trying to write an array of numbers in a file. After reading it, the result is a string, I'm wondering how to read an array of numbers or transform the string into array of numbers?

```
let file = "sample.txt"
var arr1 = [Int]()
arr1 += 1...100
var text = String(describing: arr1)
var text1 : String = String()
if let dir = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first {
    let path = dir.appendingPathComponent(file)

    // writing
    do {
        try text.write(to: path, atomically: false, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
    }
    catch {/* error handling here */}

    //reading
    do {
        text1 = try String(contentsOf: path, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
    }
    catch {/* error handling here */}
}
```

Now the question is how can I transform `text1` into an array of numbers?

Comment: you mean convert a string to an array of integers? Try splitting to list of strings, then convert every array item to int (Google it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is: if you want to save an array of **`Int`** why do write and read a **`String`**?

The easiest way to save an array of `Int` is the property list format.

Although the recommended way in Swift is the `PropertyListSerialization` class this writes and reads an array of `Int` by bridging the Swift `Array` to `NSArray`.

```
let file = "sample.plist"
let arrayToWrite = [Int](1...100)
var arrayToRead = [Int]()

if let dir = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first {

    let url = dir.appendingPathComponent(file)

    // writing

    (arrayToWrite as NSArray).write(to: url, atomically: false)

    //reading

    arrayToRead = NSArray(contentsOf: url) as! [Int]
    print(arrayToRead)
}
```

The *swiftier* way using `PropertyListSerialization` is

```
// writing

do {
    let data = try PropertyListSerialization.data(fromPropertyList: arrayToWrite, format: .binary, options: 0)
    try data.write(to: url, options: .atomic)
}
catch { print(error) }

//reading

do {
    let data = try Data(contentsOf: url)
    arrayToRead = try PropertyListSerialization.propertyList(from: data, format: nil) as! [Int]

    print(arrayToRead)
}
catch { print(error) }
```

Comment: May be JSONSerialization is another possibility how to do it easy and the "right way".